# Why am I getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent: #0 when using MediaRouteButton?

Tags: android, xml, chromecast

I'm trying to cast my app to Chromecast. I've started with adding a button, following the https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate guide.

After I have added the MediaRouteButton, I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent: #0
at android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils.calculateContrast(ColorUtils.java:93)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.getControllerColor(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:88)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.getStyledRouterThemeId(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:185)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.createThemedContext(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:60)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:124)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:120)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:408) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2198)
```

I have searched SO, and have found another, similar question, where a commenter asked to add background tag to the xml entry of MediaRouteButton. Here's my layout xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mdb_reader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mdb_book_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
            android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

(I have two layouts nested because it's used programmatically, anyway I have already tried to move the MediaRouteButton higher and it didn't help).

I've also seen some tips regarding theme, here's my `AndroidManifest.xml` `application` entry:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**vales/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.CastVideosTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="mediaRouteTheme">@style/CustomMediaRouterTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomMediaRouterTheme" parent="Theme.MediaRouter">
        <item name="mediaRouteButtonStyle">@style/CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MediaRouter.Light.MediaRouteButton">
        <item name="buttonTint">@color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values-v11/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.CastVideosTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="mediaRouteTheme">@style/CustomMediaRouterTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomMediaRouterTheme" parent="Theme.MediaRouter">
        <item name="mediaRouteButtonStyle">@style/CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MediaRouter.Light.MediaRouteButton">
        <item name="buttonTint">@color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values-v14**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.CastVideosTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="mediaRouteTheme">@style/CustomMediaRouterTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomMediaRouterTheme" parent="Theme.MediaRouter">
        <item name="mediaRouteButtonStyle">@style/CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MediaRouter.Light.MediaRouteButton">
        <item name="buttonTint">@color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Looks to me like everything should work, but I still get the damn error.

I'm using Android 26 to build.

Comment: can you tell me @color/black value?

Comment: `<color name="black">#ff000000</color>`  I can change to something else, tried few things already.

Comment: try `<color name="black">#000000</color>`. i.e without alpha channel.

Comment: tried it, the same issue. By the way, I didn't know someone specified `color/black` to be red...

Comment: yup @Krystian your colorPrimary and others should not contain alpha channel.

Comment: I haven't changed colorPrimary anywhere, so it should be the default. When I try to add this entry in my `colors.xml` I get an error: `Error:(65, 32) Color value not valid -- must be #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb, or #aarrggbb (at 'colorPrimary' with value '#ffffffff>').`  Tried `#ffffff` with same outcome.

Comment: d0h, of course, sorry, tiredness. Anyway, after setting it right I still get the same error. Tried `#ffffff` to be sure, the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who runs into this (probably while upgrading an old project), don't forget to change your activity super class from `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are directly instantiating the `MediaRouteChooserDialog` (aka. doing a bit more of a customized implementation for chromecast), and you don't want to use an AppCompat theme derivative as your app theme, you can do this:

`MediaRouteChooserDialog builder = new MediaRouteChooserDialog(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_NoActionBar);`

This passes in the default AppCompat.NoActionBar theme for the dialog to use.  You can pass whatever theme you want as long as it's a descendant of AppCompat.

Works for at least in the androidx, v7-28, and v7-28 support libraries.  Not sure about older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to override the theme in your activity style parameter:

In the android manifest the application tag should have:

```
<application
    **android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"**
     android:icon="@drawable/icon"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:name="MyApplication">
```

and in the activity tag:

```
<activity
    android:name=".VideoActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="Video"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate controller color the **primaryColor** from your current Activity theme is used. And you have to use only **fully opaque** color as **primaryColor** to show MediaRouteButton.

Please see below the source code:

```
    int primaryColor = getThemeColor(context, style,
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.colorPrimary);
    if (ColorUtils.calculateContrast(COLOR_WHITE_ON_DARK_BACKGROUND, primaryColor)
            >= MIN_CONTRAST) {
        return COLOR_WHITE_ON_DARK_BACKGROUND;
    }
    return COLOR_DARK_ON_LIGHT_BACKGROUND;
```